# after cleaning by ubuntu tweak can't login to Ubuntu correctly?

Tags: authentication, ubuntu-12.04

I cleaned all available thinks (old kernel, program conf.) by u`buntu tweak`.

All had worked ok, but when I restarted PC, I saw next info:

```
Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS nazar-desctop tty1

nazar-dezsctop login:   // I typed correct login + password
nazar-dezsctop password:

Last login: // here is date on tty

7 packages can be updated
7 updatees are security updates
```

I couldn't understand why ubuntu didn't tell me about this updates after I had cleaned.

- ***How to solve this trouble and update there packages and login safety
  to system?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try follow steps below may help you out :-

```
1) go to a text terminal using alt-ctrl-F1
2) Stop LightDM with sudo stop lightdm
3) Start GDM with sudo start gdm
4) Run sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm to set the default display manager for gdm
5) Edit /etc/X11/default-display-manager and set it to /usr/sbin/gdm if you can't run the above
6)Restart your computer and login.
```

Comment: Can you explain more about what exactly this commands do? Because I don't want to make situation much worse.

Comment: Just try these steps, dont worry it would not make your situation worse... while it will help you to solve your problem

Comment: I can do to 3 step. It print me `start unknown job: gdm`. When I type `man gdm` - it prints `No manual entry for gdm`

Comment: Ant what does this mean `set it to /usr/sbin/gdm`? Does this mean move?

Comment: Follow the link                                                       http://rolling-ubuntu.blogspot.in/2012/09/how-to-install-gdm-instead-of-lightdm.html

Comment: Are you shure we need follow this way? Coz to my mind we need to install this 7 needed packages.

Comment: try this, if it's won't help... you can ask me again, don worry

Comment: I installed gdm and did this, now I'm at system. Do I need to switch it back, again? Or it will be always?

Answer (score 1):

You did upgrade/update recently? This happened to me too, and I tried different ways to solve the problem, but no luck. I tried reinstalling lightdm, changing owner of .Xauthorithy file, installed xubuntu desktop, etc.

Finally, I fixed it by doing one thing: (go to a terminal using alt-ctrl-F1)

```
fsck /dev/sda1
```

This finds and fixes errors on the filesystem.
**Note:** use -n tag if you want to be careful of doing fsck (-n means makes no change to filesystem).

/dev/sda1 is the main filesystem you use. if you are not sure yours, simply do:

```
df
```

and it will list all the filesystems. Usually Mounted on "/" is the main one you use.